# How to automatically change notifications for access requests in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, requestaccessmail

We have a SharePoint Online environment and many sites associated with it. As we know the access request for a site can only be sent to one admin (Not even to a SharePoint or AD group), we are having issues when the admin/owner of the site leaves the organization and these access requests can't be redirected automatically to any other in the owner group of the site.

Is there a process to automate this? Like if an admin/owner of a site (whose details are provided in the access request email notification) is no longer associated with the company, this details are replaced with some one else with in the owner group of the site or Site Collection administrator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use on-premise but hoping my information might apply.  Your comment "access request for a site can only be sent to one admin" may not be true.  I recently found that if you separate email addresses with a comma, it will send to both in 2013.  In 2010 the separator was a semi-colon.

We manage this by requiring multiple site owners and having them listed in access request settings.  This way if one leaves the other still gets requests and should update the settings.

If you are looking to automate I would look at using PowerShell to run and compare access request settings to active AD users.  Not sure you can do this in Online though.

I know this isn't an answer but hoping the information might help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply it was very helpful. I am not really good at PowerShell. Do you have the PowerShell script to do this? @Josh

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the PowerShell.  That was just my first thought at an approach.  As I mentioned I am not even sure you can use PowerShell in SharePoint Online.